# MySQL - INSERT row with SELECT sub-query to fill foreign key while making sure SELECT returns a value

Tags: java, mysql, database

I have three tables

STUDENT - **student_id**, first_name, second_name, **class_id** (FK)
CLASS - **class_id**, year, special, **school_id** (FK)
SCHOOL - **school_id**, name, address

[image: Student has foreign key of Class while Class has foreign key of School]

These tables correspond to Java classes...

```
class student {
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;
    private Class class;
}
class Class {
    private int year;
    private boolean special;
    private School school;
}
class School {
    private String name;
    private String address;
}
```

I want to INSERT Student into DB.

How could I do that when:

- I don't know which entries are already in DB.
- I want to do it with as few queries as possible.

Is there any faster way than this?

1. query - INSERT INTO School VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... (while name + address will be unique composite key)
2. query - INSERT INTO Class VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... (while year + special + school_id will be unique composite key)
3. query - INSERT INTO Student VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... (while first_name + second_name + class_id will be unique composite key)

Second and Third query would use sub-queries or LAST_INSERT_ID() from previous query (but that's not usable in cases when more FK's are present)

**EDIT:** I'm NOT using ORM... just low level JDBC

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong, you are not using any ORM

Comment: While this will technically be a possible way, it would probably not fit usual usecases. a) The table has an id, so have it in your java classes too. (How do you want to change an address?) b) If you add a student, you don't want to add a school. You pick a school from a list of schools (and store that id). If you add it your way, it will create a new school if someone else changed the address in the meantime c) A student has just one class? (If it's homework, maybe reread the task) d) Simpler is oftentimes better and clearer. Dont start with the mindset "I want as little queries as possible".

Comment: Is storing an id in Java usual practice? What if I would like to store an instance of class that is not mine? Do I need to wrap it? One student = one main class... It's not homework, just example... in fact I'm using other tables with same structure. So when am I supposed to store Class & School in DB?

Comment: The pk identifies a row in the database. You will need this in some form or another (maybe, although it doesn't make much sense, in another layer) . Also: for 2 classes in the same school, you now have 2 instances of "school". You actually need a link to a javaclass, not a subclass (otherwise, changing school instance 1 doesn't change the other instance/same school). This link is the "school_id (FK)". You can abstract it, but you need some form of it. Maybe have a look at some [orm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#Java) (that is what you are creating).